# Simple message application using devexpress?

Tags: devexpress

I have an application created with `vb.net 2010 / SQl server 2008r2 / Devexpress 2011.2`
This applicaion is used by several users in network , and the database is on a server.
Now I'm thinking to create inside this application a send/receive message system.
It's a simple idea : There is a table in database that hold the messages. A user create a message in this table , and other user query this table on some intervals , and if there is a new message they can read the new record from this table and read the message.
I know how can i do this , but i don't know if there is a control on devexpress that can help me to display the messages like in a email program.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

**No**, there is no pre created control  on devexpress that can help you to display the messages like in a email program. But you can create a program with the help of these control, even in DevExpress XtraNavBar Demo have such type demo application that may help you to create such application that you want.

Check this demo screen:
[image]

Comment: Demo is provided with DevExpress setup. After installing it you can find it in the winforms demo section.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think is to use a ASPxGridview (with detail row) and to refresh it client side periodically. 
Just like the example above, you'll need three columns (1 image for the read state, 1 for the title and 1 for the sender), in the detail row you can display the message.

It should be something like this :

```
    <dx:ASPxGridView runat="server" ID="grid" DataSourceID="datasource" KeyFieldName="Id">
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewDataImageColumn FieldName="ImageUrl" Caption="&nbsp" Width="30px">
               ...
            </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Title"/>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Sender"/>
        </Columns>
        <Templates>
            <DetailRow>
                ...
            </DetailRow>
        </Templates>
    </dx:ASPxGridView>
```